# Select multiple rows into one row from 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

--BEAT TABLE--

```
CREATE TABLE beat (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  artist_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  genre TEXT
);
```

-- TAG TABLE --

```sql
CREATE TABLE tag (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  beat_id BIGINT REFERENCES beat (id) NOT NULL,
  tag_name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

One beat can have 2 `tags` for example. So, when I select `beat` I use next query:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  beat
  LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.beat_id = beat.id
WHERE beat.id = 1;
```

But this query returns me 2 rows: beat and tag with id 1 and second row beat + tag with id 2.

But I want to get it as single row: beat + tag with id 1 + tag with id 2.

UPD:
-- Example data --

```sql
INSERT INTO beat (title, artist_name, genre) VALUES ('Beat-1', 'Artist-1', 'electro;

INSERT INTO tag (beat_id, tag_name) VALUES (1, 'Tag-1');

INSERT INTO tag (beat_id, tag_name) VALUES (1, 'Tag-2');
```

-- Expected Output --

```
id 1
title Beat-1
artist_name Artist-1
genre electro
id 1
beat_id 1
tag_name Tag-1
id 2
beat_id 1
tag_name Tag-2
```

Comment: Add sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *  
FROM
  beat b
left join lateral (
    select json_agg(json_build_object('id',t.id, 'tag',t.tag_name)) as tags
    from tag t
    where t.beat_id = b.id
    ) c on true
WHERE b.id = 1
```

Comment: it works as I expected, but what is c on true?